# How to react to UITableViewCell width change?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working on a iOS 9+ app. A `UITableViewCell` subclass contains a subview which acts as container for another "progressbar-like" view:

```
UITableViewCell (content View)
+---------------------------------------------+
|  ContainerView (# = Progress View)          |
|  +--------------------------------------+   |                                               
|  |##############                        |   |
|  +--------------------------------------+   |  
|                                             |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

So, the `ContainerView` is used to position the `ProgressView` within the cell.

The `ProgressView` is **not** a real progress bar but just a `UIView`, which width should is used to represent some progress. It is positioned using Top, Bottom and Leading constraints to the `ContainerView`. The width is defined using fixed value constraint.

Thus setting the progress to some value x simply means setting the constant of the width-constraint:

```
// Set progress to .75
ProgressCell * cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kProgressCellID];
if (cell == nil)
    cell = [[ProgressCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kProgressCellID];

cell.progress = 0.75;


// ProgressCell.m
- (void)setProgress:(float)value {
    _progress = value;
    CGFloat width = self.progressContainerView.frame.size.width * _progress;
    self.progressWidthConstraint.constant = width;
}
```

This works fine in general, however in most cases it doe not work:

- The `UITableView` is loaded and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called
- The cells are created or dequeue
- Progress value is set. At this time the width of the TableView and the Cells seems to be the default width of 320px.
- After the page (and all cells) are loaded, the TableView and all cells are re-sized to the actual device width, eg. 375px.
- **Obviously x% of 320 is something else than x% of 375%. Thus the progress constraint should be updated on resize.**

Sometimes the cell is loaded with the correct width. This seems to be some kind of race-condition (wether the cell is created before or after the final width is set).

I tried to manually reload the progress/width in the cels `layoutSubviews` but this does not work either.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: reload tableview when change the value of progress. and set slider value to table cell

Answer (score 2):

Even I faced the same issue when using autolayout.

try to use below code before calculating and setting progress

```
[cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

    cell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(self.initiativeMetricTableView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(cell.bounds));
    cell.contentView.bounds = cell.bounds;
    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to call the setProgress setter (or a new method that refreshes the progressContainerView frame) whenever the cell's frame changes. E.g. you can do the following in your ProgressCell subclass

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    [super setFrame:frame];
    [self setProgress:_progress];
}
```